# Forwarding requests for relocated static content

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7, http-headers, static-content

I have a bunch of static content on a site that has always lived in the root directory like `http://mysite.com/smiley.gif`. I want to move it all to a subdirectory `http://mysite.com/images/smiley.gif`.

The problem is that years of content points to the first URL. What's the best way to forward those requests to the new locations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We've recently done exactly this. We ended up using rewrite rules though IIS because they are applied very early in the pipeline and so was the smallest performance impact. Take a look at the [UrlRewrite module](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite) for more info.

Just got our rules open, after installing the rewrite module in IIS, you add the following to your root Web.config. This rule would rewrite all *.gif requests, you might have to tailor it a bit.

```
<system.webserver>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <clear />
            <rule name="gif" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*).gif" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/images/{R:0}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webserver>
```